# How can I create a stacked barchart with timedeltas using matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

just getting into data visualization with pandas. At the moment i try to visualize a pd with matplotlib that looks like this:

```
              Initiative_160608 Initiative_160570 Initiative_160056  
Beschluss_BR         2009-05-15        2009-05-15        2006-04-07   
Vorlage_BT           2009-05-22        2009-05-22        2006-04-26   
Beratung_BT          2009-05-28        2009-05-28        2006-05-11   
ABeschluss_BT        2009-06-17        2009-06-17        2006-05-17   
Beschlussempf        2009-06-17        2009-06-17        2006-05-26
```

As you can see, i have a number of columns with five different dates (every date symbolizes one event in a total chain of five events). Now to the problem:

My plan is to visualize shown data with a stacked horizontal chart, using the timedeltas between the 5 different events (how many days have passed between the first and last event, including the dates in between). Every Column should represent one bar in the chart. The whole chart is not about the absolute time that has passed, but about the duration of the five events in relation to the overall duration of one column, which means that all bars should have the same overall length.

Yet i haven`t found anything similar or found a solution by myself. I would be extremely thankful for any kind of solution to proceed with the shown data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you are looking for, but if each column is supposed to be a bar, and you want the time deltas within each column, then you need the difference in days between each row, and I am guessing the first row should have a difference of 0 days (since it is the starting point).

Also for stacked barplots, the index is used to create the categories, but in your case, you want the columns as categories, and each bar to be composed of the different index values. This means you need to transpose your df eventually.

This solution is pretty ugly, but hopefully it helps.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Initiative_160608": ['2009-05-15', '2009-05-22', '2009-05-28', '2009-06-17', '2009-06-17'],
    "Initiative_160570": ['2009-05-15', '2009-05-22', '2009-05-28', '2009-06-17', '2009-06-17'],
    "Initiative_160056": ['2006-04-07', '2006-04-26', '2006-05-11', '2006-05-17', '2006-05-26']})
df.index = ['Beschless_BR', 'Vorlage_BT', 'Beratung_BT', 'ABeschless_BT', 'Beschlussempf']

# convert everything to dates
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format="%Y-%m-%d"))

def get_days(x):
    diff_list = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if i == 0:
            diff_list.append(x[i] - x[i])
        else:
            diff_list.append(x[i] - x[i-1])
    return diff_list
# get the difference in days, then convert back to numbers
df_diff = df.apply(lambda x: get_days(x), axis = 0) 
df_diff = df_diff.apply(lambda x: x.dt.days)
# transpose the matrix so that each initiative becomes a stacked bar
df_diff = df_diff.transpose()
# replace 0 values with 0.2 so that the bars are visible
df_diff = df_diff.replace(0, 0.2)
df_diff.plot.bar(stacked = True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me a lot.

Comment: Happy to have helped!